# How to show related post to my article after 2nd paragraph?

Tags: php, wordpress

How do I display random posts in WordPress article after 2 paragraf Wordpress?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shortcode for that, like this:

```
function sc_random_post( $atts, $content = null ) {

    $html = '';

    $posts = get_posts('orderby=rand&numberposts=1');

    foreach ( $posts as $single_post ) {

        $html .= '<a href="' . get_the_permalink( $single_post ) . '" title="' . get_the_title( $single_post ) . '">' . get_the_title( $single_post ) . '</a>';

    }


    return $html;

}
add_shortcode( 'random_post', 'sc_random_post' );
```

And then you can just use it in the content:

```
bla-bla-bla
[random_post]
bla-bla-bla
```

You could develop it further to exclude the post you are currently in - so the random would never give you the post the visitor is reading.

Comment: I want to put in the post

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. What is "the post"? The content? Thumbnail also? The excerpt? Categories / tags? Custom fields? Does it have a special formatting (e.g. CSS, order of elements, etc.)? Please see that the $single_post variable in my example holds all the data for a post - you can add any of that data to the returned HTML, formatted as you see fit.